# Grammatical differences between "curio" and "curiosity" when used as an object noun

Tags: grammar, nouns

I've recently heard the term [*curio*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curio) when talking about a strange or foreign object, whereas previously I would have used the term [*curiosity*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curiosity) in that context.

Is the use of the use of *curio* a more correct term when speaking about an **object**, compared to *curiosity* which is a better term for a **behaviour**, or can they be used interchangebly in the context of talking about an object?

For example, contrast:

- I brought this ***curio*** back from the orient, but I'm not sure what it does.
- I brought this ***curiosity*** back from the orient, but I'm not sure what it does.

Comment: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/curio Also, "a small article valued as a collector's item, esp something fascinating or unusual" (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/curio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Curio*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=curio) is a shortened form of *curiosity* that specifically refers to the “bric-a-brac” sense of the latter word. According to the Online Etymology Dictionary, it dates from 1851. The two appear to be interchangeable in that sense, although the abbreviated form is more common in my experience, especially when referring to a [*curio cabinet.*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=curio%20cabinet,curiosity%20cabinet&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) In that context, *curio* overtook *curiosity* over 100 years ago.

Comment: I'm sure *curio* is far more frequent than *curiosity* for an object. For the attitude or behaviour, I would say *curio* is impossible, don't you agree?

Comment: @Cerberus Agreed, _curio_ appears to be used only for the sense of “bric-a-brac,” which I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Hmm, upon rereading your first sentence, I guess it is not unreasonable to interpret "specifically" as "only".

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion. Do you think it's worth editing to change _specifically_ to _only_?

Comment: Oh I don't know any more, I've stared at it for too long!

Comment: I am a bit skeptical of the interchangeability, though. A *curio* is a *curiosity* but every *curiosity* is not a *curio*.

Comment: 'imterchangeable in this context'

Comment: Edited to clarify that the words are interchangeable only in the bric-a-brac sense.